# Insert space between alpha and numeric characters

Tags: ruby

I have a list of strings formatted like `"8pm9pm8pm7pm-10pm"`, and need to insert a space after `"pm"`. I want it to return something like:

```
[8pm, 9pm, 8pm, 7pm-10pm]
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: Inserting a space after each "pm" would result in `"8pm 9pm 8pm 7pm -10pm "` (a string). Your expected return value looks more like an array.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: "not sure how to go about this" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Also, your question is very unclear. What is a "list of strings"? Ruby doesn't have a list datatype in its core and standard libraries. Is that a list type you wrote yourself? Is it from a third-party library? Also, you say you want a space after every "pm", but your expected result shows a comma after every "pm", so which is it? Also, your expected result shows square brackets which you didn't mention at all in your question.

Comment: You could use scan with a regex: `str.scan(/\d+[ap]m(?:-\d+[ap]m)?/)`

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (?<=   # begin a positive lookbehind
      \d   # match a digit
      [ap] # match 'a' or 'p'
      m    # match 'm'
    )      # end positive lookbehind
    (?=    # begin a positive lookahead
      \d   # match a digit
    )      # end positive lookahead
    /x     # free-spacing regex definition mode

"8pm9pm8pm7pm-10pm".split r
  #=> ["8pm", "9pm", "8pm", "7pm-10pm"]
```

Expressed in the conventional (non-free-spacing mode) way, the regular expression is as follows.

```
r = /(?<=\d[ap]m)(?=\d)/
```

Note that a positive lookbehind followed by a positive lookahead effectively splits the string *between* characters.

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex Kayla? `/((?:\+|-)?\d*(?:am|pm))/i`

```
"8pm9pm8pm7pm-10pm8AM".split(/((?:\+|-)?\d*(?:am|pm))/i).reject(&:empty?)
[
    [0] "8pm",
    [1] "9pm",
    [2] "8pm",
    [3] "7pm",
    [4] "-10pm",
    [5] "8AM"
]
```

We take care to:

- if the number has a sign it's ok (but we ignore the grouping match with `?:`)
- any number of digits
- am or pm and we ignore the grouping match with `?:`
- case insensitive, `i` option to the regex

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need regex here? String methods are another option if not:

```
"8pm9pm8pm7pm-10pm8AM".gsub("pm", "pm ").gsub(" -", "-") #=> "8pm 9pm 8pm 7pm-10pm 8AM"
```

Gives you the string you want, or

```
"8pm9pm8pm7pm-10pm8AM".gsub("pm", "pm ").gsub(" -", "-").split(" ") #=> ["8pm", "9pm", "8pm", "7pm-10pm", "8AM"]
```

if you actually want it as an array of strings.